# Disable actionListener for JComboBox (when using anonymous class)

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, jcombobox

I am using actionListener with JComboBox event . I want to disable the listener when I manually set an item selected in my program.

Here you can see this-

```
String item=null;
String isSetByProgram=false;

jcb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                if(isSetByProgram)
                    return;
                item=jcb1.setSelectedItem();
        }
    });

    //Now set by program
    isSetByProgram = true;
    jcb1.setSelectedItem("customItem1");
    isSetByProgram=false;
```

But here I am getting this:

error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

**How can I do this without making another separate class which extends JComboBox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `item` and `isSetByProgram` to private fields of your class.  Instance fields exist specifically to store state.

```
public class MyApplication {
    private boolean isSetByProgram;
    private String item;

    // ...

        jcb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                if (isSetByProgram) {
                    return;
                }
                item = jcb1.getSelectedItem();
            }
        });

        //Now set by program
        isSetByProgram = true;
        jcb1.setSelectedItem("customItem1");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { isSetByProgram = false; });
```

Comment: why   EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { isSetByProgram = false; }); is written??

Comment: Because calling `jcb1.setSelectedItem` will place events on the AWT event queue.  If you do `isSetByProgram = false;` immediately, it may be false before the ActionListener is triggered.  This way, you can be sure you’re setting it to false after the ActionEvent has been processed.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can't. It is because your anonymous class works on copy of the variable which (if not final) can be changed and this is not allowed in this case.

Comment: I tried with final but ultimately you can not change value when using final

Comment: Yes it is how final works, you can't change final variable value or final reference if it's object reference.

Comment: Any other approach you know?

Comment: You can try to write a class which will have parameter isSetByProgram. Create object from it and send to anonymous class final reference to this object. This object won't be changed but value inisde of it can be. It should work (I haven't test it).